# Tomcat 8.5.42 permission denied when deleting files in webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, permissions, debian, user-permissions

I am currently migrating from Jdk7/Tomcat7 to JDK8/Tomcat8.5.42 on Debian 8.5. When installing a new version of my application I use a bash script which uses the `tomcat` user to make the installation, this script stoppes the tomcat, remove old `app.war` and its exploded `app` folder. With Tomcat 7 I haven't any permission issue during those operations but with the new version when deleting the `app` folder I have `rm: cannot remove ... Permission denied` error.

This is the `../webapps/`

```
4.0K drwxrwxr-x  3 tomcat tomcat 4.0K Jul  2 16:48 .
4.0K drwxrwxr-x 12 tomcat tomcat 4.0K Jul  2 16:48 ..
4.0K drwxr-x---  7 tomcat tomcat 4.0K Jul  2 15:37 app
```

I don't know if it matters but user launching the script belongs to the `tomcat` group. Also note that the `app` folder is created by Tomcat since it's the result from `app.war`.

How can I configure Tomcat to give the right rights to all users belonging to the `tomcat` group so they can delete `webapps` content. Also I don't have a `root` access, so I would like one shot solution.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Permissions on the `app` directory are `drwxr-x---` so even if the user if is in the tomcat group he will no be able to delete it, the permissions for the group are `r-x`.
Try changing directory permissions to `drwxrwx---` before removing or after deploying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to start tomcat with `umask 007` instead of 027.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask for futher reading about `umask`.

Found the hint here: https://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/035wyqr5rd/file-permissions-in-war-files

You have multiple options to set umask for a user: [How to set umask for a system-user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36220/how-to-set-umask-for-a-system-user)

Comment: Thank you for these details. Does each user have a global `umask` or does it depend on the current process? I mean if I set the `tomcat` user's `umask`, will it be apply forever or do I need to set it everytime? Thanks again

Comment: It depends on the method you choose from [How to set umask for a system-user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36220/how-to-set-umask-for-a-system-user). You can modify the tomcat startup script (e.g. setenv.sh) to call `umask` before the JVM is launched, or you can modify the configuration in `/etc` to change your setting globally. If you just enter the `umask` command within a SSH session, changes wil persist only in this session and only affect proccesses launched later from this SSH session.